# NSMutableArray adding or removing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, addition

here i have a mutable array in one vc pass in 2nd vc with some values.

I need to change values in `self.namesFoodSubCategory` problem is it also change values in first vc array.

Now if i change it to    `self.namesFoodSubCategory = [namesArray copy] ;`
now it copy well but i cannot add or remove elements  in `self.namesFoodSubCategory` it produce crash.

can anybody help me????

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andParamArray:(NSMutableArray *)namesArray
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.namesFoodSubCategory = namesArray ;

        NSLog(@"In Sec   %@",self.namesFoodSubCategory);

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `copy` method creates immutable copy of object. To preserve mutability you need to use `-mutableCopy` instead or convenience constructor (assuming you use ARC, so no need for autorelease etc):

```
self.namesFoodSubCategory = [namesArray mutableCopy];
```

or

```
self.namesFoodSubCategory = [MSMutableArray arrayWithArray:namesArray];
```

Comment: I'm used to 2nd example as well, but I think choice between them is just matter of personal preference